# Using setTimeInterval to delay a function while ajax call is running

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm a student in a coding bootcamp and having issue with delaying a function call while an ajax call is running - I know this can be handled with a Promise, but I'm not at that level yet.  I was thinking that I could use a setTimeInterval to delay the function from being called while ajax call is running, tried but just can't do it. My code is listed below - any assistance would be greatly appreciate.  The totalPrice function returns as undefined as the ajax is running, and I need to run that function after the ajax data is already available. 
Thanks, wet behind the ears coder

```
$.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET",
}).done(function (results) {
    console.log(results);
    console.log("Recipe Button Clicked!")
    //recipes is results.hits which is an array of recipes
    var recipes = results.hits;

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        console.log('STATEMENT:' + getTotalPrice(recipes[i]));
        console.log(typeof totalPrice[i]);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Do you want to reimplement the code above without using promises?

Comment: You're already using `Promise`.  From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): *The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise*

Comment: Your code is not valid JavaScript.  Please post something that at least evaluates, but preferrably an [mcve]

Comment: Please show the output of `console.log(results)` and the code for `getTotalPrice`

Comment: `The totalPrice function` - the function is called `getTotalPrice` ... there's a variable called `totalPrice` but it's an Array, not a function - so I think you've confused yourself with variable names and function names

Comment: my apologies, for the jumbled question - the problem:

Comment: I'm doing an ajax query on a recipe API.  For the first 3 returned recipes in the JSON 
object, there is a property for price(of each ingredient listed in each returned recipe).
I want to use totalPrice to sum the ingredients prices for each recipe, but I need to calculate totalPrice after the ajax call
completes. my problem is how to accomplish this using setTimeout (not at promise yet)

Comment: var totalPrice = 0;

for loop(3 times){
 total price = 0;

 $.ajax{
   query;
  }.done(function(results)
 
 totalPrice += results.price}

Comment: high level of my code setup. API returns object, but I'm not able to calculate totalPrice properly, unable to associate the ingredient prices to the specific recipe as the ajax call is running

Comment: here is code http://pasted.co/c6bd5a77